# Wordpress how to solve CORS issue undefined array key "port"

Tags: php, wordpress, cors

I have a wordpress website, which i previously duplicated and installed locally. It has a custom theme where `CORS` is defined. I'm able to go to the admin panel, but when I want to visit the site I get an error:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "port"...
```

this refers to:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? $REFERER['scheme'].'://'.$REFERER['host'] . ($REFERER['port'] ? ':' . $REFERER['port'] : '') : '*'));
```

I tried to change it to:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

but then I get an access denied.

I tried to deactive plugins and change permalinks, but with no luck.

Does someone know whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to a php version issue... I assume you are working with php 8,

Please try this:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $REFERER['scheme'].'://'.$REFERER['host'] . (isset($REFERER['port']) ? (':' . $REFERER['port']) : '') : '*'));
```